# Merge character values from two columns and put parentheses around

Tags: r

I have a dataset like this:

```
code <- "A.123"
name <- "John"
df <- data.frame(code,name)

   code name
1 A.123 John
```

I'm trying to combine these two columns so the new column is like this:

```
code <- "A.123"
name <- "John"
new_column <- "John (A.123)"
df <- data.frame(code,name,new_column)

   code name   new_column
1 A.123 John John (A.123)
```

I tried this code but I'm not sure how to incorporate the parentheses in this code:

```
df <- df%>%
  mutate(new_column = paste(name,code))
```

I would appreciate all the help theres is! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sprintf` in `base R`

```
 with(df, sprintf("%s (%s)", name, code))
[1] "John (A.123)"
```

---

Or using `glue`

```
library(dplyr)
library(glue)
df %>%
   mutate(new_column = glue("{name} ({code})"))
   code name   new_column
1 A.123 John John (A.123)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the parentheses around when using `paste`.

```
paste0(df$name, " (", df$code, ")")
#[1] "John (A.123)"
```

or

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
  mutate(new_column = paste0(name, " (", code, ")"))
#  code name   new_column
#1 A.123 John John (A.123)
```